# Integration - U substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am given the following indefinite integral:

$\int x\sqrt{1+2x}~dx$ using the substitution $u=\sqrt{1+2x}$

I am not sure where to begin, I know that $du=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}$

But how can I get this integral in terms of $u$ when there is a $x$ in front?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: We have $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}\,dx$, so $dx=u\,du$. Note that $x=\frac{u^2-1}{2}$. So with the substitution you are using, we end up with $\int \frac{u^2-1}{2}u^2\,du$. Multiply through and integrate.

Comment: I tried that But I am still getting the wrong answer. This is what I did $\frac{1}{2} \int u^4 - u^2 du$ Is this correct? Integrating gives me $\frac{u^5}{10} - \frac{u^3}{6} + C$ It seems to be still incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: So the result i get is: $1/10\, \left( 1+2\,x \right) ^{5/2}-1/6\, \left( 1+2\,x \right) ^{3/2}$ Which still seems to be incorrect...

Comment: Apart from the missing $+C$, it is correct. The expression can be manipulated into various equivalent forms.

Comment: You are welcome. You can differentiate the (correct) answer that you got. You will first get $\frac{1}{2}(1+2x)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}(1+2x)^{1/2}$. After taking out a common factor $(1+2x)^{1/2}$ and simplifying, you wil get your original integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Use $x=\frac{u^2-1}{2}$ to get dx = u du

Answer (score 0):

Try $u = 1 + 2x$, so $x = (u  - 1)/2$.  This will make the integral easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem requires that I use the given U substitution as noted above.

Comment: What you see above is more work, but it will do the job with that substitution.